# Nulling array of structure in structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct

In my program I have to make structure that contains array of other structure(that is a list).

```
struct ListEl {
string text;
ListEl *next;
};
struct hashTable {
int size;
ListEl *tab;
};
```

And in main I have to NULL all elements of "tab" however I'm unable to do so:

```
hashTable *hashingTable;
hashingTable->size = 256;
hashingTable->tab = new ListEl[hashingTable->size];

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

    hashingTable->tab[i] = NULL; //<--------------Cannot do that
}
```

And in this for loop I'm getting an error from compiler : no operator"=" doesn't match these operation arguments, type operands "ListEl = int".
What am I doing wrong?

In the meanwhile I can do:

```
struct ListEl {
string text;
ListEl *next;
};


int main(){
    ListEl *tab[256];
     for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        tab[i] = NULL;
   }
}
```

What's the diffrence?

Comment: why don't you use memset for setting all the values to zero. Have a look at my answer. Use are assigning a NULL to structure that is not allowed. You can do NULL assignment to pointer only.

Comment: Thank you! How would I do that with using NULL then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to initialize the array members.  The struct has an implicit constructor which sets all fields to 0.

So when you create an array using `new ListEl[hashingTable->size]`, each member of the array is constructed using this default constructor.

One problem you do have however is not initializing `hashingTable`.  You dereference this pointer without giving it a value.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can give it a value by using `new`:

```
hashTable *hashingTable = new hashTable;
```

EDIT:

The implicitly defined constructor won't explicitly initialize members which are primitive objects such as pointers or integer types but will initialize members which are class objects.  You'll need to explicitly define a constructor to initialize the `next` member:

```
struct ListEl {
    string text;
    ListEl *next;
    ListEl():text(),next(NULL) {}
};
struct hashTable {
    int size;
    ListEl *tab;
    hashTable:size(0),tab(NULL) {}
};
```

Comment: @Michał Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use constructor to initialize the `hashTable` and `ListE1`.
It could be something like this:

```
struct ListEl
{
  string text;
  ListEl *next;

  ListE1(){text = ""; next = NULL;}
};

struct hashTable
{
  int size;
  ListEl *tab;

  hashTable(int n){size = n;tab = new List[n];}
};
```

Then you can initialize it simply by:

```
hashTable* hashingTable = new hashTable(256);
```

Answer (score 0):

memset() can be used for setting all the values in the list to NULL.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct ListEl
{
  string text;
  ListEl *next;
};
struct hashTable
{
  int size;
  ListEl *tab;
};

main ()
{

  hashTable *hashingTable;
  hashingTable->size = 256;
  hashingTable->tab = new ListEl[hashingTable->size];

/*  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
      hashingTable->tab[i] = NULL;  //<--------------Cannot do that
    }
    */
    memset(hashingTable->tab,0,(hashingTable->size * sizeof(ListEl)));
}
```